# Persist RecycyclerViewAdapter data on activity recreation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an `Activity` with a `Fragment` inside.
In that fragment there are `RecyclerView`, and `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

In fragment's `onCreate` I'm doing this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("TAGGG", "onCreate: ");
    // Database handler
    Contract.DbHelper dbHelper = new Contract.DbHelper(getContext());
    dERecyclerViewAdapter.setEntries(dbHelper.readAllEntries());
}
```

Everytime the `Activity` is recreated(up navigation, rotation changes) data is being read again from the database.
What is the correct way to store it?

Comment: Use a separate singleton class and store the list there and upon activity recreation get it from singleton class.

Comment: You can use onRestoreInstanceState() and  onSaveInstanceState() methods to save data on configuration change and For fragment just add nnew fragment in stack instead of replacing so previous fragment state will be maintained

Comment: Singleton class is tempting but then I will have to propagate changes to 3 places: db, adapter and singleton class.

@bindal
I could but, my list object has a lot of fields, creating parcellable from it would be hell.

Comment: And put your code Database fetching code in onActivityCreated instead of onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the savedInstanceState  to store the data through a bundle. You can store it like this

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   //Use the bundle to store data
}
```

And retrieve it like this

```
@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
      //Use the savedInstanceState to get the stored result 
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `CursorLoader` class.  Your situation is exactly what this class was intended for.

The loader itself can persist between configuration changes, so that when you call `onCreate`, if the loader has already performed the query it will just provide the data it already read rather than re-query the database.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Also http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html